# Fixing oily chili

Tags: chili

I fried my ground beef and onions for chili in olive oil and didn't drain it. Now my chili tastes oily. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: In the future, you likely don't need to add any oil at all - ground beef usually has plenty in it.

Answer (score 12):

Put the chili in the fridge overnight, and the oil will gather at the top.  Then you can just scrape it off with a spoon.

Comment: If it's oily enough, it'll lift off in a sheet -- but I sometimes have to readjust the spices, as the fat soluble flavors get taken with it.  (and the sheet of grease is bright orange).

Comment: Note that the fridge trick works great for hamburger grease, but olive and most vegetable oils won't congeal at that temperature.